# JSON storage on Android

Tags: android, json, performance, api, local-storage

I have made an api that throws out a JSON file which is equivalent to 12kb of disk space. I have an android app that will somewhat take this data to update it's content/images/etc.

[Here is the JSON response](http://pastebin.com/v1rx8VyH)

I was wondering what would be the best way to store this data? I have seen three different methods... Key Pair Storage, File Storage and SQLite Storage.

What would you suggest to be the best solution for my scenario?

I should mention that the app. Will be getting this response regularly, checking for any updates. Other API's are used to update the data within this JSON response.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sqlite will be best option i think..using that you can update also regularly..

Comment: so how do I go about this? I can't visualise why I would need to update it when I can just fetch it again? After calling another API...

Comment: oke then use key pair storage also..

Answer (score 0):

I think in your scenario key pair storage would be useful. As any other method would make it time and space consuming and with key pair it would be more dynammic for you to perform.

Comment: I'm edging more towards this... so basically if a user has wifi get the data and stick it in a somewhat global variable. if not get a local copy and use that.. Sound good?

Answer (score 0):

Two points on the other answer:

1. With a 12 kB String, it is still negligible. If it grows, there might be a lag. Consider `SharedPreferences.Editor.apply()`.
2. You might want to make it easier on your app, parse the data when it arrives and put it into NoSQL-database, like [JasDB](https://github.com/oberasoftware/jasdb/wiki).

Comment: @wonderkid: I have not used it. It has a download size of about 5.2 MB (uses native code). JasDB (see update) looks promising, but also quite large. Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403174/is-there-any-nosql-database-as-simple-as-sqlite/32247005?noredirect=1#comment56202256_32247005?